# Как расшифровать файлы, зашифрованные Samsung?

Tags: криптография, шифрование, samsung

У меня `Samsung A3(2017)`, на нем находились прям ну **ОЧЕНЬ** важные файлы и, когда я вернул телефон к заводским настройкам, я то ли не увидел, то ли не было ничего, но оказывается мои файлы на карте памяти были зашифрованы. (честно не помню, чтобы я их шифровал вообще) И после сброса настроек я больше не могу просто так их расшифровать. Сейчас они находятся на ноутбуке, а старая карта памяти, которая была в телефоне на момент шифрования, утеряна.

Я пытался через другую карту памяти восстановить их, но все бестолку.

И вот вопрос: можно ли как нибудь расшифровать эти файлы? Я имею в виду может, можно узнать для начало каким алгоритмом шифрует файлы `Samsung`, а потом не знаю хотя бы брутфорсом их расшифровать. Эти файлы мне **ОЧЕНЬ** важны.

*P.S.* сразу хочу извинится за такой вопрос на этом форуме, не знаю на какой форум можно еще написать с этой проблемой.

**Дополнение**

Нашел на сайте [Касперского](https://noransom.kaspersky.com/ru/) список программ для расшифровки файлов, зашифрованные программами-шифровальщиками. Может какая-то из этих программ может помочь? Скачал первую, а там просит файлы расширения, которых я не знаю. У меня зашифрованное видео имеет расширение `mp4`.

Comment: Попробуйте задать вопорс на 4pda (рус) и xda (англ) в теме девайса

Comment: @ДавидМанжула спасибо, только что задал этот вопрос на этих форумах.

Comment: Версия Андроида какая установлена в вашем аппарате?

Comment: Если вам удалось что-то восстановить, можете поделиться опытом, у меня та же ситуация с A3 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации Samsung Knox](https://docs.samsungknox.com/admin/knox-platform-for-enterprise/kbas/kba-360039577713.htm)

> Available on all Samsung Galaxy devices shipping with Android 9.0 or higher and Knox 3.3 or higher, FBE protects files in the user data Flash partition. Each file is independently encrypted using AES-256-XTS, with a unique File Encryption Key that is derived from a Primary Key. In FBE, Primary Keys are randomly generated and protected by the TEE-based Keymaster component

В переводе на общедоступный язык означает, что для девайсов с версией Android > 9.0 используется механизм раздельного шифрования файлов (то есть не шифрование всего диска). Для шифрования файлов применяется алгоритм AES-256-XTS (AES - алгоритм, 256 - длина ключа, XTS - мода сцепления блоков). При этом ключи шифрования генерируются рандомно и хранятся в защищенном чипе (что собственно и составляет т.н. Samsung Knox).

Поскольку ТС рапортует, что телефон был сброшен к заводским найтройкам, что автоматически означает, что ключи хранившиеся в Knox уже потеряны - соответственно задача взлома Knox, для вытаскивания ключей (по слухам для аппаратов с процессорами Qualcomm это возможно) уже не стоит.

Соответственно остается только брутфорс. Проблема с брутфорсом усугубляется тем, что **каждый** файл шифруется своим уникальным ключом, так что для каждого файла придется запускать свой брутфорс.

Я бы рекомендовал действовать приблизительно так:

1. Поскольку речь идет о MP4 файлах, можно вырезать первый килобайт (кратно 8 байтам) шифрованного видео и сигналом к успешному подбору ключа будет дешифровка [сигнатуры заголовка видео](https://www.file-recovery.com/mp4-signature-format.htm)
2. Далее берем в руки инструмент, желательно с поддержкой перебора через GPU
3. Удачи!

Поиск инструмента для брутфорса безусловно кроме гуглинга можно и нужно [начать отсюда](https://forum.antichat.ru/categories/111/).